# How to calculate two-point Padé approximant?

Tags: pade-approximation

Wikipedia mentions [two-point Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant#Two-points_Pad%C3%A9_approximant). I don't have access to the reference provided (Yoshiki Ueoka, *Introduction to multipoints summation...*).

I checked also chapter 8 (*The N-Point Padé Approximants*) in the George A. Baker's *Esssentials of Padé Approximants*, but could not translate the theory to a practical example myself.

Questions:

1. How to calculate two-point Padé approximants in general?
2. Could you provide an example? Let's say `e^x` at `0` and `1` of order `3/3`?